# unable to retract SharePoint solutions

Tags: 2007, visual-studio, stsadm, retraction

I am having trouble retracting solutions in SharePoint 2007.

I used both the retract solution button and the stsadm command in command line.  The timer job was created in both instances, but it never gets run... it just sits in the timer job definition.  The Status of the target just said "Retracting (scheduled at m/dd/yyyy MM:SS AM/PM)".  I've waited for a long time and nothing happens.

Has anyone experienced this before, and does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: @BeraCim: Do you solve this problem? I faced with the same and don't know how to solve it. I use Windows Server 2008 r2 x64. Could you you please comment if find solution.  In my situation both SharePoint Administration and Timer are running. stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs returns "Operation completed successfully", but solution still retracking (

Comment: @Kai: my timer jobs were already up and running so all I needed was to manually execute the jobs in the queue using execadmsvcjobs. I could see the jobs getting executed in the command prompt. You might want to first check whether the jobs have been placed in the timer queue in central admin (Operations -> Timer job definitions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if your Windows `SharePoint Services Administration` and `Windows SharePoint Services Timer` jobs are running.

Also after ensuring, run this command

`stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs`

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the OWSTIMER service is running
2. Check the ULS logs
3. Try [SharePointOverflow](http://www.sharepointoverflow.com) :-)

Comment: @pst: I had a look at my log and found pages of stuff from OWSTIMER that says "Preserving template record with size..." and "The previous instance of timer job 'blah', id {}, for service {} is still running, so the current instance will be skipped.".  Not sure what that means or how to solve that at all... and SharePointOverflow didn't return anything obviously useful.

Comment: Hi ..did anyone solved this problem.I have got the same issue and even execadmsvcjobs command is not working for me..Is there any solution that you came across